# How to compute the numbers of the form 5i+1, i between 1 and 20 with emacs?

Tags: bash, emacs

First off, I'm not only new in emacs, but in unix in general. I've tried writing:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..20}  
do

    j=(5*$i)+1
    echo "$j"
 done
```

The result: 
(5*1)+1
(5*2)+1
(5*3)+1
(5*4)+1
(5*5)+1
(5*6)+1
(5*7)+1
(5*8)+1
(5*9)+1
(5*10)+1
(5*11)+1
(5*12)+1
(5*13)+1
(5*14)+1
(5*15)+1
(5*16)+1
(5*17)+1
(5*18)+1
(5*19)+1
(5*20)+1

How do I actually sum?

Comment: With emacs or with bash? You show a bash script, what does emacs have to do with it?

Comment: BASH calculations are of the format `result=$(( calculation ))`, i.e. `j=$(( (5*$i) + 1 ))` (PEDMAS is properly applied so the inner parentheses are actually redundant). Note that BASH arithmetics is integer only!

Answer (score 0):

pipe it to bc, nice short easy answer;

```
echo "$j" | bc
```

Comment: ps, bash can do math but not decimals, bc can do decimal places with scale.